# VueJS2 - bind part of the class name

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to change (bind dynamically) just a part of the class name. For example I have this alert box:

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Alert!</h4>
        Success alert preview. This alert is dismissable.
    </div>
```

This only part of the class which is dynamic is the **alert-success** class - the **success** of the class name can be **danger, info...** (depends on the type of message).

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular `v-bind`:

```html
<div :class="'alert alert-' + classType + 'alert-dismissible'">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Alert!</h4>
    Success alert preview. This alert is dismissable.
</div>
```

Being `classType` the property (you can name however you want it). By "property" I mean it can be a `data`, a computed or even a method call.

Notice the argument to `:class` is a JavaScript expression:

```js
'alert alert-' + classType + 'alert-dismissible'
```

So mind the quotes.

You can also use [array syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax), if you find it clearer:

```html
<div :class="['alert', 'alert-' + classType, 'alert-dismissible']">
```

As reminded by [@Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925492/vuejs2-bind-part-of-the-class-name/49925526?noredirect=1#comment86867272_49925526) in the comments, you can also use both bound (`:class`) and unbound (`class`) attributes at the same time, Vue will merge them appropriately:

```html
<!-- if classType equals to the whole class name, like 'alert-active' -->
<div class="alert alert-dismissible" :class="classType">
<!-- if classType equals to just a part of class name, like 'active' -->
<div class="alert alert-dismissible" :class="'alert-' + classType">
```

Comment: Works like charm :). Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sasha you can use like `<div class="alert alert-dismissible" :class="classType">`, for static class, just put them into non bind class, for dynamic class, bind it with your data/computed property. it will make the codes clearer.